# Small web page with news and files

Tags: web-forums, communication, tools, wiki, blog

I'm a part of a band, and it happens, that I'm most tech advanced guy of all. We have troubles organizing our notes and we somehow solved them, using Google drive. Now we have some concerts and we need some sort of time planning also. So I want to organize some corner in the web, which should:

1. **Take least amount of my work to setup**
2. **Have some sort of news/timeline**, to post something like "Next concert at 19:00 15/01/16 in pub"
3. **Have file storage** to store our notes, texts. It will be great advantage if it has some version control
4. **Not be part of social network**, because, some of our memebers does not have such network, and we respect their choice
5. **Be private,** i.e. should require registration and invitation from moderator to view content

As I see it, it should be some site, where I can login, organize our dashboard, invite others and then we can contribute to this workspace.

Comment: Sounds like Google drive + Google calendar + Google spreadsheets(docs) is all you need. You just need to share/maintain 3 URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Yahoo groups? https://groups.yahoo.com/neo  Its not the most functional capabilities, but the other newer groups services, such as Google Groups, or Facebook groups would violate your request not to be part of a social media group.

Another newer service that people are using is Slack which has many of the features you are asking for: https://slack.com/?tiered_signups=1&story=video&v=3